# Stage: Orientation of the robot

Tags: simulation, stage, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a simple program using stage simulation where I want to find the present position of the robot in the format of (x , y , theta ).

I am not able to understand how to convert the orientation into a understandable format of theta.

How do I go about from this data
x: -10.6492617064
y: 7.43208867907
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.210458934126
w: 0.977602698977

Is there a function or formula that I can convert orientation data into theta.

-Suraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9864/stage:-orientation-of-the-robot./) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're working in python, it's as simple as using this method found in [transformations.py](http://code.google.com/p/ros-geometry/source/browse/tf/src/tf/transformations.py):

```
import tf 
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
...
(roll,pitch,yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
```

In C++ it's just `tf::getYaw(quaternion)`. See [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b)

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5